How to configure MassTransit and RabbitMQ for multitenancy
I need to connect our multitenant app (using finbuckle) to MassTransit/RabbitMQ.
The app is using:

Finbuckle for multitenant support
Autofac combined with .NET Core DI

Requirements:

Currently, tenants are added through a tenant admin app, and no application restart is needed. However, in the future, restarting the app when a new tenant is added is an option, allowing me to register MassTransit bus instances at startup.
I need to grant other companies access to specific tenants.
I would like to register consumers per tenant (using tenant configuration) because not all tenants will integrate with same applications. This is optional requirement.
Consumer must be fetched/instantiated using DI

Two potential approaches seem viable:
1. Single Virtual Host with Tenant-Specific Queue Names
As described in this article, this approach mirrors a multi-tenant database setup where each table has a tenantId column, isolating tenant data without separate databases.
Pros

Simplicity in configuration
No need to pre-create RabbitMQ virtual hosts

Cons

I’m unsure how to implement permissions to prevent one tenant from accessing another tenant's queues.

2. Dedicated Virtual Host per Tenant
Pros

Complete tenant isolation
Easier to restrict tenants to their own virtual hosts, preventing cross-tenant access

Cons

Each new tenant requires creating a new virtual host in advance.

Additional Considerations:

Implementing Solution 2 would likely require manual bus configuration for each virtual host. However, manual bus configuration is no longer documented, which suggests it might not be a recommended practice.
MassTransit’s Multibus feature isn’t acceptable in this case, as it requires a separate interface for each bus instance, meaning the app would need redeployment for every new tenant.
I’d prefer not to use Autofac multitenancy, as Finbuckle already manages multitenancy within the app.

Any advice or code examples would be greatly appreciated!

Multi-tenant support is in development for MassTransit. It would replace Finbuckle entirely (the functionality is similar) and works purely with MS DI. There is no ETA on a release, but it would support both scenarios albeit without the "security between tenants" on a single virtual host similar to how it's done with a single database for all tenants. Work is prioritized by customers, and none are currently pushing for this to be rushed.

@ChrisPatterson Is it possible to configure and initialize one IBus instance per tenant using Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq? Each instance would be connected to its virtual host. Do you know of sample code working that way?

I do not, and if you're configuring the container (Autofac) yourself, you can probably do whatever you want but many of the container-based features of MassTransit will not be available.

I solved this by emitting an IBus extending interface for each tenant. Then, I called the AddMassTransit method for each emitted interface.

internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args);
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false).Build();

        MassTransitConfig massTransitConfig = config.GetSection("MassTransitConfig").Get<MassTransitConfig>();

        builder.ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            BusControlFactory busControlFactory = new BusControlFactory(new MassTransitConfigDataProvider(massTransitConfig), services, [typeof(NotificationCreatedConsumer1).Assembly]);
            busControlFactory.Initialize();
            services.AddSingleton(busControlFactory);
        });

        var app = builder.Build();

        // USAGE:
        BusControlSupport busControlSupport = new BusControlSupport(app.Services.GetRequiredService<BusControlFactory>(), app.Services);
        IPublishEndpoint publishEndpoint = busControlSupport.GetPublishEndpoint("tenant1");
        Console.WriteLine(publishEndpoint);

        IClientFactory clientFactory = busControlSupport.GetClientFactory("tenant2");
        IRequestClient<ICreateOrder> requestClient = clientFactory.CreateRequestClient<ICreateOrder>();
        Console.WriteLine(requestClient);

        app.Run();
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets MassTransit objects belonging to tenant
/// </summary>
public class BusControlSupport
{
    private readonly BusControlFactory busControlFactory;
    private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;

    public BusControlSupport(BusControlFactory busControlFactory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        this.busControlFactory = busControlFactory;
        this.serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public IPublishEndpoint GetPublishEndpoint(string tenantIdentifier)
    {
        Type openType = typeof(Bind<,>);
        Type[] typeParameters = [busControlFactory.BusTypes[tenantIdentifier], typeof(IPublishEndpoint)];
        Type closedType = openType.MakeGenericType(typeParameters);

        //Bind<IBus, IPublishEndpoint> publishEndpointBind = (Bind<IBus, IPublishEndpoint>)serviceProvider.GetService(closedType);
        object publishEndpointBind = serviceProvider.GetService(closedType);

        return (IPublishEndpoint)publishEndpointBind.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
    }


    public IClientFactory GetClientFactory(string tenantIdentifier)
    {
        Type openType = typeof(Bind<,>);
        Type[] typeParameters = [busControlFactory.BusTypes[tenantIdentifier], typeof(IClientFactory)];
        Type closedType = openType.MakeGenericType(typeParameters);

        //Bind<IBus, IPublishEndpoint> publishEndpointBind = (Bind<IBus, IPublishEndpoint>)serviceProvider.GetService(closedType);
        object clientFactoryBind = serviceProvider.GetService(closedType);

        return (IClientFactory)clientFactoryBind.GetType().GetProperty("Value");
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Initializes one MassTransit IBus per tenant
/// </summary>
public class BusControlFactory
{
    private readonly IMassTransitConfigDataProvider massTransitConfigDataProvider;
    private readonly IServiceCollection services;
    private readonly Assembly[] consumerAssemblies;

    internal IDictionary<string, Type> BusTypes { get; } = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

    public BusControlFactory(IMassTransitConfigDataProvider massTransitConfigDataProvider, IServiceCollection services, Assembly[] consumerAssemblies)
    {
        this.massTransitConfigDataProvider = massTransitConfigDataProvider;
        this.services = services;
        this.consumerAssemblies = consumerAssemblies;
    }

    public void Initialize()
    {
        // get the AddMassTransit<TBus> method using reflection
        Type registrationExtensionType = typeof(DependencyInjectionRegistrationExtensions);
        IEnumerable<MethodInfo> methodInfos = registrationExtensionType.GetMethods().Where(mi => mi.Name == nameof(DependencyInjectionRegistrationExtensions.AddMassTransit));
        MethodInfo? addMassTransitMethodInfo = null;

        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in methodInfos.Where(mi => mi.IsGenericMethodDefinition && mi.GetGenericArguments().Length == 1))
        {
            Type genericArgumentType = methodInfo.GetGenericArguments().First();
            Type[] genericParameterConstraints = genericArgumentType.GetGenericParameterConstraints();
            if (genericParameterConstraints.Length == 1 && genericParameterConstraints.First().FullName == typeof(IBus).FullName)
            {
                addMassTransitMethodInfo = methodInfo;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (addMassTransitMethodInfo == null)
            throw new Exception("addMassTransitMethodInfo == null");

        // execute AddMassTransit<TBus> for every tenant
        foreach (MassTransitTenantConfigData tenantConfigData in massTransitConfigDataProvider.TenantConfigDatas)
        {
            Type busType = TenantBusInterfaceGenerator.CreateTenantBusInterface(tenantConfigData.TenantId);
            BusTypes[tenantConfigData.TenantId] = busType;
            MethodInfo addMassTransitMethod = addMassTransitMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(busType);

            if (addMassTransitMethod == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not create AddMassTransit generic method for {busType.FullName}.");

            // Define the configuration action
            Action<IBusRegistrationConfigurator> configureAction = 
                busConfigurator =>
                {
                    busConfigurator.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                    busConfigurator.AddConsumers(consumerAssemblies);

                    busConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq((context, busFactoryConfigurator) =>
                    {
                        busFactoryConfigurator.Host(tenantConfigData.Uri, hostConfigurator =>
                        {
                            hostConfigurator.Username(tenantConfigData.Username);
                            hostConfigurator.Password(tenantConfigData.Password);
                        });

                        busFactoryConfigurator.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                    });
                };

            // invoke AddMassTransit<busType>
            addMassTransitMethod.Invoke(null, [services, configureAction]);
        }
    }
}


/// <summary>
/// Emits interface that extends IBus interface
/// </summary>
public static class TenantBusInterfaceGenerator
{
    private static readonly AssemblyBuilder AssemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("DynamicTenantBuses"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
    private static readonly ModuleBuilder ModuleBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");

    public static Type CreateTenantBusInterface(string tenantName)
    {
        string interfaceName = $"I{ToValidClassName(tenantName)}Bus";
        TypeBuilder typeBuilder = ModuleBuilder.DefineType(interfaceName, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Interface | TypeAttributes.Abstract);
        typeBuilder.AddInterfaceImplementation(typeof(IBus));

        return typeBuilder.CreateTypeInfo().AsType();
    }

    private static string ToValidClassName(string input)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
            throw new ArgumentException("Input cannot be null or whitespace.", input);
        
        string cleaned = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^A-Za-z0-9\s]", "");

        TextInfo textInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo;
        string pascalCaseName = textInfo.ToTitleCase(cleaned).Replace(" ", "");

        if (char.IsDigit(pascalCaseName[0]))
            pascalCaseName = "_" + pascalCaseName;

        return pascalCaseName;
    }
}

